# how to add a vertical line to the right to the button such that the line should appear in between the search bar and that button

Tags: html, css

The line should be beside the button and before the search bar

```css
.vertline{
  border-right:4px solid black;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertline">
  <button class="hin"></button>
  <label>Home</label>
  <span><input type="text" placeholder="search videos" name="search"></span>
  <span><input type="submit" value="" class="tel"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, just put the the vertline class to the the span with the input field. Heres an example:

```css
.vertline {
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="hin"></button>
  <label>Home</label>
  <span class="vertline"><input type="text" placeholder="search videos" name="search"></span>
  <span><input type="submit" value="" class="tel"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line{
  border-left:4px solid;
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertline">
        <button class="hin"></button>
        <label>Home</label>
        <span><input type="text" placeholder="search videos" name="search"></span>
        <span class="line"><input type="submit" value="" class="tel"></span>
    </div>
```